# Python: Numpy __deepcopy__ TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, copy

I'm trying to use deepcopy on an ndarray, and the line looks like this:

```
foo = myArray.__deepcopy__()
```

I'm getting:

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I need a deep copy, and I can't import copy.

Comment: _"I can't import copy"_ - why not?

Comment: Unless you're using an object array (which you shouldn't), `myArray.copy()` should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The special `__deepcopy__` method takes a `memo` arg. You can pass an empty dict for this:

```
foo = myArray.__deepcopy__({})
```

Comment: Weird, I didn't see that in the documentation, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Since when could the memo be a tuple? The docs say it's a dict.

Comment: @user2357112 I would have naturally said `dict` too, but the numpy doc used a tuple as sample: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#special-methods

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: That looks like a formatting problem to me, not a sample input. It wouldn't be the only formatting problem; a few lines down, we have `ndarray.__new__((S, ...)`, with mismatched parentheses.

Comment: @user2357112 You are right, but I am particularly surprised as to why it works with almost any container type

Comment: I suspect `__deepcopy__` is provided just so that `copy.deepcopy` works.  It may not be doing anything with that argument which can be anything, even `None`.  Is there any evidence that this deepcopy is doing anything other than `myArray.copy()`?  There are various ways of copying arrays, some letting you specify `order`, `subok`, etc.

Comment: @hpaulj I later figured it takes just about any object. It appears to be only a placeholder arg for the special method.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant code in `copy` is:

```
def deepcopy(x, memo=None, _nil=[]):
    """Deep copy operation on arbitrary Python objects.

    See the module's __doc__ string for more info.
    """

    if memo is None:
        memo = {}
        ....
           copier = getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)
            if copier:
                y = copier(memo)
...
# If is its own copy, don't memoize.
if y is not x:
    memo[d] = y
    _keep_alive(x, memo) # Make sure x lives at least as long as d
return y
```

So `memo` is a `memoize` dictionary, at least when used 'properly'

So if I pass a dictionary as `memo`, it changes that:

```
In [160]: dd={}
In [161]: A2=copy.deepcopy(A,memo=dd)
In [162]: dd
Out[162]: 
{2814755008: array([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]), 2814808588: [array([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
          [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]],

         [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])]}
In [163]: id(A)
Out[163]: 2814755008
In [167]: id(dd[id(A)])
Out[167]: 2814568472
In [168]: id(A2)
Out[168]: 2814568472
```

The `memo` keeps a record of the copy.  I don't know what the 2nd item is.

And if I ask for another deep copy with the same memo, it gives the memoized array rather than a new copy.

```
In [173]: A3=copy.deepcopy(A,memo=dd)
In [174]: id(A2)
Out[174]: 2814568472
In [175]: id(A3)
Out[175]: 2814568472
```

If an array is object dtype, the `deepcopy` might make a difference.  The memo certainly looks different.

Answer (score 1):

The [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) contains the documentation for `__deepcopy__`, and it is quite clear what the argument should be:

> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`. The former is called to implement the shallow copy operation; no additional arguments are passed. The latter is called to implement the deep copy operation; **it is passed one argument, the memo dictionary.**

But if you're not implementing a customized deep-copyable class you generally don't need to bother about this, simply use `copy.deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random((100, 100))
deepcopy(arr)
```

It will take care of the `memo`-dict without your intervention. Note: Most of the `__*__` are designed that way, you generally don't and shouldn't call them directly. So like you use `x in y` instead of `y.__contains__(x)` you normally use `copy.deepcopy(x)` instead of `x.__deepcopy__(dict())`.