# Python Copying an array without inplace replacement

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace

I have medium experience with numpy arrays and I dont remember that this have happened me before, example:

```
y=np.array([1,2,3])
yy=y[:]
yy[2]=4
print y
```

and it delivers

```
[1,2,4]
```

why is this happening? i tried using numpy.copy and still it is replacing the original array

Comment: `y[:]` is a copy for lists, but just a `view` for arrays.

Comment: so what would be the proper way to copy the original array?,'cause i tried using `yy=np.copy(y)` and still got the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `copy.deepcopy`.

```
In [108]: import copy

In [109]: yy = copy.deepcopy(y)

In [110]: yy[2] = 4

In [111]: y
Out[111]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

`deepcopy` makes a recursive copy all the way to the deepest level of nesting.

Note that a deep copy may be over kill for 1D arrays, so in that case you may use `copy.copy` which makes a shallow copy.

*Edit:* While `copy.*copy` might seem redundant in the face of `np.copy`, their usefulness is seen in special cases where you might have an array with `dtype=object` (as discovered by @hpaulj).

Comment: @jmparejaz Do upvote/mark accepted if it helped. It helps me out as well as the community. Cheers.

Comment: Deepcopy is not needed with numpy arrays. The numpy copy is sufficient, regardless of the number of dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, didn't see the numpy tag when I wrote this. You are right. Won't edit since I'd just sound redundant.

Comment: I just checked, `deepcopy` is useful if the dtype is object.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. Learned something new. Will edit that in!

Comment: Deepcopy gets even deeper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846309/python-numpy-deepcopy-typeerror

Comment: @hpaulj Not sure where to even begin with that... 9_9

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what is going on when you are using `np.copy`, but you shouldn't see modifying the resulting array effect the original:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: y = np.array([1,2,3])

In [3]: yy = y.copy()

In [4]: yy[2] = 4

In [5]: print y
[1 2 3]

In [6]: print yy
[1 2 4]

In [7]: zz = np.copy(y)

In [8]: zz[2] = 5

In [9]: print zz
[1 2 5]

In [10]: print y
[1 2 3]
```