# Python copy.copy() vs NumPy np.copy()

Tags: python, numpy, copy

Is there any situation where I would want to use NumPy's `np.copy()` over Python's `copy.copy()` method? As far as I can tell, both create shallow copies, but NumPy is limited to arrays. Is there any performance or special handling by NumPy that's not accounted for by `copy`?

Comment: For starters, the implementation would differ. Furthermore, you don't have to `import copy` to use `copy`.

Comment: We can double check this, but I think `copy.copy` just delegates the action to the objects own copy method, where possible.  In fact you can read the `copy.copy` code yourself.  `arr.__copy__` is a method.  `np.copy` is also python code.

Comment: I see and use `arr.copy()` most often.

Comment: `deepcopy` has an added `memo` parameter, which is discussed at [Python: Numpy __deepcopy__ TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846309/python-numpy-deepcopy-typeerror)

Answer (score 2):

[`numpy.copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) allows more control over the memory layout of the result with the `order` argument, and it always produces an array, even if given some other array-like. Also, you don't have to separately import the `copy` module.

Comment: But, does importing `copy` have any side-effects beyond the extra line of code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are side effects and numpy code is around 20% faster than pure python for float64 types.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from copy import copy

In [3]: arr = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)

In [4]: %timeit copy(arr)
535 ms ± 97.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [5]: %timeit np.copy(arr)
453 ms ± 19.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [6]: %timeit arr.copy()
456 ms ± 22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```