# Python deepcopy() vs just initiating a numpy array in terms of run-time speed?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, copy, deep-copy

I am curious if

```
elevation_arr = numpy.zeros([900, 1600], numpy.float32)
climate_arr = copy.deepcopy(elevation_arr)
rainfall_arr = copy.deepcopy(elevation_arr)
```

is faster or slower to execute than

```
elevation_arr = numpy.zeros([900, 1600], numpy.float32)
climate_arr = numpy.zeros([900, 1600], numpy.float32)
rainfall_arr = numpy.zeros([900, 1600], numpy.float32)
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using `copy..deepcopy()`? I think `elevation_arr.copy()` would anyways be equivalent to a deep copy, since the elements of `elevation_arr` are immutable ints.

Comment: @fountainhead I wanted to make sure the values wouldn't be references. I didn't know that immutable values would work like that. They are technically floats though aren't they?

Comment: True, they're `float32s`. But immutable, nevertheless, as are `ints`. My point is that, given an aggregate data structure (in this case numpy array) consisting of many objects, a shallow copy is good enough if the objects in the aggregation are all immutable. Only when the objects are mutable, it becomes important to make the copy a deep one, by making copies of the elements themselves.

Comment: @fountainhead Oh, I see. Thanks! I didn't know that.

Comment: For an array like yours: `copy.copy(arr)`, `copy.deepcopy(arr)`, `arr.copy()`, `np.array(arr, copy=True)` all time the same. `deepcopy` is only significantly different if the array has object dtype (same as if a list contains lists or dictionaries).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42846309/python-numpy-deepcopy-typeerror.  `arr.copy()` is commonly used when we want a copy of an existing array.  `deepcopy` is rarely used with numpy objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy_zeros` performs slightly better for smaller arrays and much better for larger arrays as shown below

```
import copy
import numpy as np

def deep_copy():
    elevation_arr = np.zeros([900, 1600], np.float32)
    climate_arr = copy.deepcopy(elevation_arr)
    rainfall_arr = copy.deepcopy(elevation_arr)
    return 

def numpy_zeros():
    elevation_arr = np.zeros([900, 1600], np.float32)
    climate_arr = np.zeros([900, 1600], np.float32)
    rainfall_arr = np.zeros([900, 1600], np.float32)
    return

%timeit deep_copy()
# 4.13 ms ± 585 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit numpy_zeros()
# 3.01 ms ± 195 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

For a 10000 x 10000 array, following are the timings. `numpy_zeros` simply outperforms

```
%timeit deep_copy()
# 569 ms ± 50 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit numpy_zeros()
# 15.6 µs ± 1.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: I didn't know you could time stuff like that, thank you.